# Is it valid to apply JsonConverter for query string arguments

Tags: asp.net-web-api, json.net

All,

My team has recently encountered with a roadblock of using JsonConverter with HttpRequest arguments.

My API method definition is as below

```
[HttpGet]
[GET("Values/Data/{inputString}/{inputDateTime:datetime}")]
public HttpResponseMessage GetResponseForData(string inputString, [JsonConverter(typeof(DateTimeToTicksConverter))] DateTime inputDateTime) 
{
      // do something here
}
```

The `DateTimeToTicksConverter` is to intercept the `DateTime` attributes and then transform as defined. When this attribute is applied on the attributes of a model it works fine. However when the attribute is defined as in the API above it doesn't intercept during request.

I would like to know if it is valid to expect `JsonConverter` to intercept the request parameters?

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not meant to be used there, that attribute is just metada which json.net looks for when serializing a class to JSON, but webapi has no knowledge of it.

You can achieve what you want using a custom httpparameterbinding. You can find more info here http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api